# Cannot resolve 'setCasServerUrlPrefix' in 'SingleSignOutFilter'

Tags: spring, spring-security, cas

After a recent upgrade of a Spring Boot application that relies on CAS for authentication, the project no longer compiles due to the fact that the `setCasServerUrlPrefix` method can't be found on `SingleSignOutFilter`:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setCasServerUrlPrefix(java.lang.String)
  location: variable singleSignOutFilter of type org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter
```

The involved code is:

```java
@Bean
public SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter() {
    SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
    singleSignOutFilter.setCasServerUrlPrefix("...");
    singleSignOutFilter.setIgnoreInitConfiguration(true);

    return singleSignOutFilter;
}
```

How to update the code to still set this value even though the setter doesn't exist anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this method has been removed since `cas-client` 3.6.0 ([reference commit](https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client/commit/fdc948b8ec697be0ae04da2f91c66c6526d463b5#diff-676b9d196aacd4b54bc978c62ccbacd8d29552fcd694061355bd930405560fb5)) as it was not used internally so calling `setCasServerUrlPrefix` is no longer needed.

Not really semantic-version-friendly as there were no deprecation cycle and this change is introduced in a point release but at least, it is safe to remove from your code base.