# After updating spring boot to 2.3.5 Unable to resolve SingleSignOutFilter.setCasServerUrlPrefix()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

After a recent upgrade of a Spring Boot application that relies on CAS for authentication, the project no longer compiles due to the fact that the setCasServerUrlPrefix() method can't be found on SingleSignOutFilter.

My Code is:

```
@Bean
public SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter() {
    SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
    singleSignOutFilter.setCasServerUrlPrefix("...");
    singleSignOutFilter.setIgnoreInitConfiguration(true);
    return singleSignOutFilter;
}
```

Error Message is Below:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setCasServerUrlPrefix(java.lang.String)
  location: variable singleSignOutFilter of type org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter
```

Comment: Well there is no such thing as "just" upgrading. Looks like another upgraded dependency (maybe through Spring Security) which also changed. So look at the class and find the replacement for that property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot resolve 'setCasServerUrlPrefix' in 'SingleSignOutFilter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354432/cannot-resolve-setcasserverurlprefix-in-singlesignoutfilter)

Comment: @JoshuaSwink this doesn't resolve my problem